# How can I show the linearity of a function which consists of other nonlinear functions?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, machine-learning

I stumbled upon a question from an old university exam and I cannot bring myself to find an argument that explains the solution. Consider the following scenario:
Given the function from the picture where $\forall i:x_i, w_i \in \mathbb{R}$. The question is now "Is the function a linear method?".
[image]

The options are:

1. True
2. False
3. depends on f
4. depends on g
5. depends on f and g

My initial guess would have been answer 5 - it depends on the choice of f and g. The solutions says that it only depends on the choice of f. So choosing a linear f and nonlinear g should result in a function which is linear in w. Writing the function in the following form would imply for me that a nonlinear g would make the resulting function nonlinear:

$g(w^T f(Wx)) = y$ with $w = \begin{pmatrix}w_1^{(2)}\\w_2^{(2)}\end{pmatrix}^T$ and $W = \begin{pmatrix}w_{11}^{(1)}  w_{12}^{(1)}\\w_{11}^{(1)} w_{22}^{(1)}\end{pmatrix}$

Where is the error in my train of thought?

Comment: $x \rightarrow W x$ and $x \rightarrow w^T x$ are linear. We can't say anything about $y$ if we know nothing about $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Exactly, the solution says that we only need to assume that f is e.g. linear for the function to be linear in w. But in my book g also does have an impact on that and I can't figure out whether the solution from the exam is incorrect or my train of thought is not right.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because you can apply directly the inverse of the nonlinear transformation $g$  to the output values $z=g^{-1}(y)$ so you have just a transformed set of values under the form:
$$\omega^T f(Wx)=z$$
So the problem is only related to the linearity of $f(x)$... I am thinking in the example of doing a linear regression of exponential distributed data.... I first apply an affine log transformation to my outputs, and then I can use a simple linear reagression.